# How to identify the type of motion in this case?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, vectors

I'm new to Kinematics.

I have the velocity vector as **v** $ = (2i - 4j) \ m/s $ , and the acceleration vector as  **a** $ = (-2i + 4j) \  m/s^2 $ .

Now I need to tell what type of motion this is in terms of a whether it is uniformly accelerated or non-uniformly accelerated. 
And the second parameter is - whether it is two dimensional motion or one dimensional motion.

Comment: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/vect.html is a good site for these type of homework like  questions and you could also edit your question to add in this tag. Also  Physics SE does not answer homework type questions. https://www.boundless.com/physics/textbooks/boundless-physics-textbook/two-dimensional-kinematics-3/vectors-41/components-of-a-vector-219-6269/

Comment: https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange

Comment: Do you know what the terms *uniformly accelerated* and *2-dimensional motion* mean?

Answer (score 2):

The coefficients of your unit vectors are just numbers, so your acceleration is constant -- meaning uniformly accelerated.  In this case you will get two possible trajectories.  The path is either a piece of a parabola or is straight-line motion with acceleration.  The straight line case will occur if the velocity and acceleration are co-linear, and the parabolic case if they are not.  Compute the cross-product of the velocity and the acceleration.  If you get zero, then the vectors are co-linear.

Answer (score 0):

a = -(2i-4j)
a = -v

This means acceleration is in opposite direction of velocity and  independent of time so it is uniform retarding acceleration.

And as you can see a is defined by i and j ( unit vector for x and y axis respectively) hence the the motion takes place in x-y plane 
and therefore it  is a 2-D motion.

Comment: Answering homework questions may be well intentioned, I do  appreciate that, but it is  against the policy of this site. In this case, the OP has learnt less than they might have by following the links.

Comment: @Countto10 ok thanks i will keep that in mind

Comment: Rohan, this is not 2D. If a motion is along only one path - in other words, of you could have described it with just one axis - then it is 1D. It just happens to be written in a 2D coordinate system. You could also have written it in a 3D coordinate system, such as $$\vec v=2i-4j+0k$$ And if you tilted the system and choice a different orientation, none of the three terms would be zero. A 1D motion in a 2D space is still a 1D motion.

Comment: This may seem like nitpicking, but it's not: $a  \neq -v$ because they describe different physical quantities.  Always treat the physical units like they were algebra symbols of their own.

Answer (score 0):

- Is it uniform acceleration?
  Is the acceleration of constant magnitude?
  Is the direction of the acceleration constant?
  If the answer to both questions is "Yes" then the acceleration is uniform.
- Is the motion in one dimension or in two dimensions?
  Can the velocity $\vec v$ and the acceleration $\vec a$ be written in terms of the same (unit) vector $\vec w$ such that $\vec v = v_{\rm w} \vec w$ and $\vec a = a_{\rm w} \vec w$ where $v_{\rm w}$ and $a_{\rm w}$ are the components of the velocity and acceleration of the vector $\vec w$?
  If the answer is "Yes" then the motion is one dimensional.